# Conditional Trigonometrical identities

Tags: trigonometry

> Find numerical value of $\sin x+\cos y$ if
>   $$(\sin x)^4+(\cos y)^4+2=4\sin x*\cos y$$

This problem appeared in my school exam and I somehow managed to eliminate cosy but couldn't get the answer.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1177017/how-to-prove-the-identity-sin-x4-cos-x42-4-sin-x-cos-y

Comment: @Dr.MV It turns out that any attempt to solve for $y$ in terms of a real $x$ yields complex values for $y$, _except_ in two cases (modulo $2\pi$), as in WimC's answer. So you are right in principle, but here the extra information that $x$ and $y$ are supposed to be real is enough to get to an answer.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, the question you linked to was deleted, hence not visible to most users.  In that version, the $(\cos y)^4$ on the left hand side was given as $(\cos x)^4$, rendering the problem unsolvable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$x^4+y^4-4xy+2=(x^2-y^2)^2+2(xy-1)^2.$$ So if this expression vanishes then $xy=1$. The only solutions on $[-1,1]^2$ are $(-1,-1)$ and $(1,1)$ so $x+y \in \{-2,2\}$.

Comment: You are correct but the sum will not lie in the range but will be equal to -2 or 2 because there is an equality not an inequality.

Comment: $\{\}$ denotes a set, not a range.

Comment: Sorry for that .